# How to remove all map layers from kepler.gl dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl, react-map-gl, kepler.gl

[image]

I have added a div and dropdwn, on each option I have uploaded geojson data using addDatatoMap in reactjs . 
On each time I selected the option , this uploaded the respective layer ,
But I am not able to remove the previous layers,
So any code or example to reset / clear map layers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many research I found the solution , so posted it to save other's time

```
import KeplerGlSchema from 'kepler.gl/schemas';
import { visStateUpdaters } from 'kepler.gl/reducers';

// // Clear Uploaded Data
RemoveUploadedData() {
// // returns uploaded Data on map
const dataToSave = 
KeplerGlSchema.getDatasetToSave(this.props.demo.keplerGl.map);
console.log('dataToSave', dataToSave);

// // returns uploaded layer config on map
const configToSave = 
KeplerGlSchema.getConfigToSave(this.props.demo.keplerGl.map);
console.log('configToSave', configToSave);

var layerConfigs = configToSave.config.visState.layers;

// // Removed each uploaded layers
if (configToSave && layerConfigs.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < layerConfigs.length; i++) {
        this.props.demo.keplerGl.map.visState = 
              visStateUpdaters.removeDatasetUpdater(            
              this.props.demo.keplerGl.map.visState,
            { key: dataToSave[i].data.id }
         )
       }
     }
   }
```